# c# Determine inherited class based on Enum and call child method accordingly?

Tags: c#, inheritance, parent-child

I would like to create a base class that will process a message queue, with a number of inherited classes for the different types.  Now I only want to call the base class' ConsumeMessage method, but is there a way where the base class can instantiate the inherited class and call the child Consume class?  This will prevent long case and if statements for every child type.

The child class can be determined by an Enum (or something else).

Something like this:

```
public enum EnumMessageTypes
{
    Type1 = 1,
    Type2 = 2
}

void main()
{
   new Queue().ConsumeMessage();
}

public class Queue
{
     public abstract EnumMessageType MessageType();
     public virtual bool ConsumeMessage 
     {
            var Messages = GetMessagesFromDB(); //Get all unconsumed messages from DB
            foreach (int messageID in Messages)
            {
                //Determine child class from Messages.MessageType (which is the same as the Enum value)
                ChildClass = ??;  //Can this be done?
                ChildClass.ConsumeMessage(messageID);
            }

            return true;
     };
}

class Type1 : Queue
{
    public override EnumMessageTypes MessageType()
    {
        return EnumJobType.Type1;
    }

    //Process the item.
    public override bool ConsumeMessage(int messageID)
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Alternative:

```
void main()
{
    var Messages = GetMessagesFromDB(); //Get all unconsumed messages from DB
    foreach (int messageID in Messages)
    {
        ChildClass = ??;  //Can I instantiate a child class 'abstractly'
        ChildClass.ConsumeMessage(messageID);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes - I suppose it can be done.... But please don't do it that way. Instantiate the correct derived `Queue` to start with. The base class should never know anything about its derived classes, doing so breaks so many rules.

Comment: You don't have different kinds of queues, you have one kind of queue that can process different kinds of messages. Inheriting from `Queue` doesn't make much sense in that context, but a `Message` class hierarchy might be useful.

Comment: Thanks Colin. I agree with your statement.  But I'm also trying to save on code with many if's or case statement (and ease the burden when new child classes are created).  I'll update my question with another alternative, that might serve the same goals.

Comment: Thanks Pieter. I've changed my coding to have a Queue class and a Message class (with the child types inhertiing from Messages). For simplicity I will not update the question as the source of question will remain the same.

Comment: As Slava's answer shows, you can use `Activator.CreateInstance`, but it also accepts a `Type` as argument. Instead of using class name strings, you could create a (static) array of `Type`s, so an enum value can be used as index to get its matching type, which can then be passed to `CreateInstance`. Personally, I'd just create a 'factory' method with a `switch` statement inside. You need some kind of selection mechanism anyway, so you might as well keep it simple and straightforward.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet, instead of `switch`, at existed case, it will be better to determine class name with the help of reflection.

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov: why would that be better? That requires enum and class names to match, so renaming some will 'silently' break things. That's more brittle.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet, yes, but author wrote, that enum values same as class names and if you will have hundred classes, it will be very big switch construction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var className = typeof(EnumMessageTypes).GetFields()[(int)message.MessageType].Name;
var ChildClass = (Queue)Activator.CreateInstance(null, className).Unwrap();
ChildClass.ConsumeMessage(message.ID);
```

if you have namespace, you should also specify it:

```
var ChildClass = (Queue)Activator.CreateInstance(null, "MyNameSpace." + className ).Unwrap();
```